# Custom VF page that embeds list views based on profile and record based related list on selecting record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to VF Pages. I would like to build a VF page which has list views based on the user profile that logs in(existing list views).

In the list view if user clicks on a record i should be able to show the Custom object related lists.

For example i want my page to look like:

```
<apex:page standardController="myObject__c">
<apex:enhancedList type="myObject__c"> (This list view is based on user profile)
(On click of record in above list view show below)
<apex:relatedList list="myObject__r"/>
</apex:page>
```

Please give me some ideas on how to acomplish this.

Comment: your question is not clear and secondly put the logic in the code which you are trying to achieve

Comment: @SantanuBoral :  In a vf page, on click of record in enhanced list view, it has to display related lists details associated with that object. I wanted to know how it can be doen in salesofrce.